# Asp.Net HttpContext does not contain a definition for SignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having to work with an old mvc project in asp.net 4.6.1 and I'm trying to add a login feature.

But there's an error with the HttpContext part, it says: "HttpContextBase does not contain a definition for SignInAsync and the best extension method overload AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync(HttpContext, ClaimsPrincipal) requires a receiver type HttpContext".

The code is as follows:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

[Route("login")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string username, string password, string returnUrl)
   var claims = new List<Claim>
   {
        new Claim("username", username)
   };
   var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
}
```

I was using this same block of code in a recent .net 5 project which works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you use this? SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync ?

Comment: They have docs (I tried it in .net 6): [Use HttpContext from custom components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components). And `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync` works.